# Is there a solution faster than O(n^2) for this greedy/sorting problem?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, sorting, greedy-algorithms

In a market there are N different items where each item is unique and identified by id (1-N). There are also K buyers with names (1-K). Each buyer has 2 items that they want to buy (A, B), where A is the id of the first item and B is the id of the second item. Each buyer will either buy one or no item. If the first item is available they buy it, and if it isn’t  available they buy the second item.

Print the order of the buyers that will maximize items sold.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: This looks like a maximum matching problem in a bipartite graph.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write the constraints: Both N and M are at max 10^5 so I can’t really convert it into a graph using an adjacency matrix because it would take too much memory.

Comment: I’m not sure how to use adjacency list in the maximum matching problem

Comment: Actually I dont think maximum matching algorithms work here because of the fact that buyers prioritize certain items. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just do a maximum matching in a bipartite graph corresponding to buyers and items where each buyer is connected to the two items she/he wants to buy.

It is obvious that the maximize items sold cannot exceed the value of the maximum matching. On the other hand, we can always turn the maximum matching into a valid maximum matching, meaning we can arrange the order of the buyers such that the items matched are sold to the corresponding buyers.

Suppose in the maximum matching, buyers in $A$ first-match (match their favorite items) items in $B$ and buyers in $A'$ second-match (match their second favorite items) items in $B'$. We adjust the matching as follows. Note we always maintain the set $A, B,A',B'$ such that $A$ ($A'$) and $B$ ($B'$) respectively represent the buyers and the items that are first-matched (second-matched). We do not state explicitly how elements are added in or deleted from these sets for simplicity. For a buyer $a$, we denote by $\mathrm{first}(a)$ and $\mathrm{second}(a)$ the items she/he wants to buy respectively.

```
For each a in A' such that first(a) is not in B:
    If first(a) is not in B':
        replace the second-match a-second(a) with a first-match a-first(a) 

# Now for each a in A', first(a) is either in B or in B'

For each a1, ..., an in A' such that first(a1) == second(a2), first(a2) == second(a3), ... and first(an) == second(a1)
    replace the second-matches [a1-second(a1), ..., an-second(an)] with the first-matches [a1-first(a1), ..., an-first(an)]
```

After the adjustment above you can check that the resulting matching is a valid maximum matching. The buyers in $A$ come firstly, the buyers $a\in A'$ such that $\mathrm{first}(a)\in B$ come secondly, and the rest buyers in $A'$ come lastly. Note the order of the rest buyers must obey the rule that if $\mathrm{first}(a_1) = \mathrm{second}(a_2)$ then $a_2$ must come before $a_1$. You can obtain this order by topological sorting.

Comment: You need to add a third option for each buyer, namely not buying anything.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus If a buyer does not buy anything, he will not be matched in the maximum matching.